# Accept 3 dictionary inputs with keys Name, age and total marks. print them in a table in ascending order of marks

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to write a program to store Information of 3 students in to a dictionary with keys Name, age and total marks. Accept inputs from keyboard and print them as a table in ascending order of marks
Here is the code i have written.

```
import ast
from collections import OrderedDict
d={}
for i in range(3): 
  a = raw_input("Please enter details of student %d: " %(i+1))
  d[i] = ast.literal_eval(a)
print "\nname\tage\tmarks\n"
d_ascending = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]['marks'])
for i in range(3):
    print "%s\t%d\t%d" % (d_ascending[i][1]['name'],d_ascending[i][1]['age'],d_ascending[i][1]['marks'])
```

On giving 3 input as

```
{"name":"X","age":20,"marks":200}
{"name":"Y","age":21,"marks":900}
{"name":"Z","age":20,"marks":700}
```

output is :

```
name    age     marks

X       20      200
Z       20      700
Y       21      900
```

I want the table as :

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  name  |  age   |  marks |
+--------+--------+--------+
| X      | 20     | 200    |
| Z      | 20     | 700    |
| Y      | 21     | 900    |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

I need this type of table. Also I would like to know whether there are any other easy ways to do this program. Just to know more possibilities to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I guess you can try prettytable：

```
$ pip install PrettyTable
```

I'll show you a simple example:

```
>>> from prettytable import PrettyTable
>>> table = PrettyTable(['name', 'age', 'marks'])
>>> table.add_row(['X', 20, 100])
>>> table.add_row(['Z', 20, 700])
>>> table.add_row(['Y', 21, 900])
>>> print(table)
+------+-----+-------+
| name | age | marks |
+------+-----+-------+
|  X   |  20 |  100  |
|  Z   |  20 |  700  |
|  Y   |  21 |  900  |
+------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: This is ok when the values are assigned inside the code..here i need to accept the input from keyboard as a dictionary

Comment: Yeah, you can use your code to get the input and render the table with `PrettyTable`. The example I give is to show you the basic usage for the `PrettyTable`.

Comment: @NooNaMarJa For example, you can add the table row like this: `for item in d_ascending: table.add_row([item[1][key] for key in ['name', 'age', 'marks'])`